# React Type Error when implementing authentication with Python

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement authentication with Python and React, and I have this error message on the front-end.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined

And this is my SignIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Icon, Input } from "antd";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { authLogin } from "../store/actions/auth";

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const { error, loading, token } = this.props;
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    if (token) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="gx-login-container">
        <div className="gx-login-content">
          <div className="gx-login-header gx-text-center">
            <h1 className="gx-login-title">Sign In</h1>
          </div>
          {error && <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>}
          <React.Fragment>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="gx-login-form gx-form-row0">
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }],
              })(

              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" loading={loading} disabled={loading}>
                Log in
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </React.Fragment>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.auth.loading,
    error: state.auth.error,
    token: state.auth.token
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(authLogin(username, password))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignIn);
```

I have deleted the input part because I don't think that there is some problem. If someone think that the input part is the problem I will gladly post it.

Here is my reducers/auth.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";
import { updateObject } from "../utility";

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false
};

const authStart = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    error: null,
    loading: true
  });
};

const authSuccess = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    token: action.token,
    error: null,
    loading: false
  });
};

const authFail = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    error: action.error,
    loading: false
  });
};

const authLogout = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    token: null
  });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.AUTH_START:
      return authStart(state, action);
    case actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS:
      return authSuccess(state, action);
    case actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL:
      return authFail(state, action);
    case actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT:
      return authLogout(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Post `updateObject` also.

Comment: export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
  return {
    ...oldObject,
    ...updatedProperties
  };
};

Answer (score 0):

The errors says that it cannot find the property loading in an undefined object. Maybe your state.auth is null or undefined. Try logging the state.auth to check if it has a value.

Comment: When I console log state.auth, it says 'state' is not defined  no-undef.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your issue. You have initial state as,

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false
};
```

and you are trying to get the state in `mapStateToProps` as,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.auth.loading,
    error: state.auth.error,
    token: state.auth.token
  };
};
```

Here you are trying to access state using `state.auth.loading`, but you don't have `auth`  object in your initial state and you get `undefined` error. You can fix this like,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    error: state.error,
    token: state.token
  };
};
```

**Note:** If your `updateObject` function returning state with `auth` object then you need to correct that. Your initial state and returned state should be of same pattern.

Comment: Now it says that getFieldDecorator is undefined, Type error as well. Should I delete it?

Comment: Can you post your input also.

Comment: Which type error you are getting? If the error is for `{this.props.error.message}` then agian you don't have `message` in state, you need to directly use `{this.props.error}`